# Detect workstation/System Screen Lock using Python(ubuntu)

Tags: python, system, locking, ubuntu

Is there anyway that we can detect when the system/screen gets locked and notify some event to trigger in Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a possibility to be notified when the screen becomes locked/unlocked with DBus, this is reference on [GnomeScreensaver](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Is_there_a_way_to_perform_actions_when_the_screensaver_activates_or_deactivates.3F__Or_when_the_session_becomes_idle.3F) showing the basics of it.

I am not DBus expert, but there are bindings for python, so you can listen for DBus events in python. Combinig the two, you should be able to get what you want:-).

Here is a python-dbus [programming tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Dbus) on wikibooks.

Comment: Cool, I'll look into this DBUS