# How to Detect workstation/System Screen Lock in ubuntu using java?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm trying to note down workstation/System screen lock of each employee working in ubuntu OS. I needed to store these record in a DataBase. using JAVA. I have searched all over and got on idea for UBUNTU; But got idea how to do the same in windows OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35243/is-there-a-programmable-way-to-tell-if-the-screen-is-locked):

```
gnome-screensaver-command -q | grep "is active"
```

Use the [Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) class to execute that command and read back the result.

**EDIT**: use `grep -q`

Here an example how to use it:

```
public class ScreenSaver {

  /*
   * Pipes are a shell feature, so you have to open a shell first.
   * 
   * You could use process.getInputStream() to read the output and parse it.
   * 
   * For productive use i would prefer using the Inputstream.
   */

  private static final String COMMAND = "gnome-screensaver-command -q |  grep -q 'is active'";

  private static final String[] OPEN_SHELL = { "/bin/sh", "-c", COMMAND };

  private static final int EXPECTED_EXIT_CODE = 0;


  public static boolean isScreenSaverActive() {
    final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process = null;
    try {
      /*
       * open a shell and execute the command in that shell
       */
      process = runtime.exec(OPEN_SHELL);
      /*
       * wait for the command to finish
       */
      return process.waitFor() == EXPECTED_EXIT_CODE;
    } catch(final IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(final InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
  }


  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Screensaver is active: " + isScreenSaverActive());
  }

}
```

**EDIT:** added perl script watching dbus signals. Source:
[Gnome Screensaver FAQ](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Is_there_a_way_to_perform_actions_when_the_screensaver_activates_or_deactivates.3F_Or_when_the_session_becomes_idle.3F)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $cmd = "dbus-monitor --session \"type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver',member='ActiveChanged'\"";

open (IN, "$cmd |");

while (<IN>) {
    if (m/^\s+boolean true/) {
        print "*** Screensaver is active ***\n";
    } elsif (m/^\s+boolean false/) {
        print "*** Screensaver is no longer active ***\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I got your code working, but I wrote your code inside a java code and packed it as a .jar file to run. Wile I lock or unlock the screen i need to run this file how to do it. I got an idea to monitor screensaver and run my jar file by the code instructed by Mr. viki.omega9, but it gives syntax error. which I mentioned in comment of his answer.

Comment: I too have a similar type of code as you gave. **The thing I need now is to make this jar file execute only while screen is locked and unlocked.**

Comment: So you need something like to listen to a event when the screen is locked/unlocked and then execute the jar file? Please clarify, i don't really understand what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Take a look at: http://live.gnome.org/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Is_there_a_way_to_perform_actions_when_the_screensaver_activates_or_deactivates.3F_Or_when_the_session_becomes_idle.3F

Comment: The script is written in perl, it's no shell script!

Comment: I have came through this code already and in this I got syntax error while I run it which I mentioned in comment of @viki.omega9 's answer. [Here is the code.](http://pastie.org/pastes/3212744/text). This was the error I got : `/home/sathishkumarkk/Desktop/userinfo.sh: 2: my: not found  /home/sathishkumarkk/Desktop/userinfo.sh: 4: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`

Comment: so how do I deal with it? I have no Idea!

Comment: I have added the sample script(FAQ). Just copy paste it to a file, chmod +x, and execute. Replace the print commands with your java stuff and you should be done.

Comment: It is working on my side (Ubuntu Lucid 10.04 LTS). Perl version: `v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi`

Comment: @ Sathish Kumar k k: replace `#!/bin/bash` in your code with `#!/usr/bin/perl`. Than execute the script: `./scriptname` or `perl scriptname`. You must not use a bash shebang line if you want to run perl!

Comment: You are right and I saved the code as `.sh` and executed with `bash`. Now I saved it as `.pl` and executed as `perl sample.pl`. so now it works and I have a doubt at screen unlock even, whether it is activated while I move the `mouse/use the keyboard?` or `while I enter the password and hit enter?`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6879/discussion-between-sathish-kumar-k-k-and-ortang)

Comment: @OrtwinAngermeier i tried you code for ubuntu machine, but i return always false value even screen is locked

Answer (score 1):

Try having a look here, ( Similar duplicate), [Detect workstation/System Screen Lock using Python(ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395579/detect-workstation-system-screen-lock-using-pythonubuntu))

[GNOME Screensaver FAQ](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Is_there_a_way_to_perform_actions_when_the_screensaver_activates_or_deactivates.3F__Or_when_the_session_becomes_idle.3F) This should be an awesome reference for you to get up to speed. I suppose you are using GNOME.

Comment: I have seen these sites already and I get syntax error while I run in my terminal. As I'm new to Linux I cant able to debug those syntax error. the error I get this        `**/home/sathishkumarkk/Desktop/userinfo.sh: 2: my: not found
/home/sathishkumarkk/Desktop/userinfo.sh: 4: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")**`

Comment: You should paste your entire script as nobody can debug your errors without looking at code. Use pastie.org and show your code.

Comment: here is the shell script which i ran in terminal. [My shell script inside .sh file](http://pastie.org/pastes/3212744/text)

Comment: I think its a good idea if you could brush up your bash scripting skills first. The most obvious error in the second line was, 'my $cmd' which is wrong and should be just, '$cmd'.

Comment: I had checked by removing `my`later it shows `=` is not found and what about the error in 2nd line?. one the answerer `@ ortang` told that this code is perl and not a bash scripting. since i'm very new to linux i cant make the difference, and what do you say for what he has said?

Comment: Linux has nothing to do with choice of language. I assumed you knew what you were writing. Since you save it as a shell script, I assumed so.

Comment: yes. since I'm new to linux I'm not aware of these thing. But now I learned what to do and now its working. Thanks!